# В VS code в файле js не отображается подсказка css (например ID,class)

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="clkDiv"> //Этот id не видно в js файле.
Hello world
</div>
```

и когда я пишу `clkDiv.`, то после точки не отображаются методы например addEventListener

---

[image: Вот id мой]

Не отображает в файле js id

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот js файл.  как сделать так чтобы вот в подсказках был этот айди и методы потом определялись после точки

Comment: <div id="clkDiv">
    Hello world
    </div>

Comment: Вам надо улучшить вид вопроса. Очень сложно читать и непонятно, в чём проблема конкретно.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то ты хочешь чтобы он дописывал за тебя методы, возможно vsc думает что это не js файл, посмотри справа внизу что за файл он определяет.

Comment: Он определяет js файл там всё нормально.